# SDN-4 connection pooling

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using spring-data-neo4j 4.1.3.RELEASE with spring boot application. Using neo4j in server mode, community edition - version 3.1.0 with http driver ( would be changing to bolt driver soon)

I am using neo4j session with request scope

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
```

I would like know how to enable connection pooling with http driver or bolt driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection pooling is enabled by default in SDN/OGM for both http and bolt driver. The default pool size is 50.

To modify the pool size you can set following property in `ogm.properties`:

```
connection.pool.size=50
```

or if you use java configuration:

**OGM 2.0.x** (used by SDN 4.1.x)

```
org.neo4j.ogm.config.DriverConfiguration#setConnectionPoolSize
```

**OGM 2.1.x** (used by SDN 4.2.x)

```
org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder#connectionPoolSize
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped !